# Converting MP4 into m3u8 with multiple subtitle tracks using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I'm currently working on a video pipeline that will take in an mp4 file and n number of webvtt files and outputting an m3u8 file with selectable subtitle tracks, and I'm having some difficulty figuring out the correct incantations with ffmpeg.

The following is the command I'm using right now to test everything out before integrating it into my project:

```sh
ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -i sample-vtt-en.vtt -i sample-vtt-es.vtt \
  -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1 -map 2 \
  -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s webvtt \
  -metadata:s:s:0 language=en \
  -metadata:s:s:1 language=es \
  -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls \
  -master_pl_name master.m3u8 \
  out/sample.m3u8
```

When running the above, I get the following error

```sh
[webvtt @ 0x7fb6c6075a00] Exactly one WebVTT stream is needed.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:3 --
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:2 (webvtt (native) -> webvtt (native))
  Stream #2:0 -> #0:3 (webvtt (native) -> webvtt (native))
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

Additionally, when I process this with a single webvtt file, it doesn't error out, but the output isn't quite right. The biggest issue is the master playlist does not contain any subtitle information and doesn't recognize any of the tracks. The sample.m3u8 playlist does seem to understand about the subtitle tracks, but they are split in all kinds of odd ways.

Can someone help me out with what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the [HLS muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-2) currently does not allow variant streams that only contain subtitles. I don't use HLS, so you'll want to investigate further in case I'm wrong, or if you're a reader in the future the situation may have changed.

Sub-optimal workaround is to add audio to the variant stream with the `-var_stream_map` HLS muxer option. Something like:

```
ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -i sample-vtt-en.vtt -i sample-vtt-es.vtt \
  -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:a -map 1 -map 2 \
  -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s webvtt \
  -metadata:s:s:0 language=en \
  -metadata:s:s:1 language=es \
  -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls \
  -var_stream_map "v:0,name:video a:0,s:0,language:eng,name:english a:1,s:1,language:spa,name:espanol"
  -master_pl_name master.m3u8 \
  out/sample.m3u8
```

Comment: let me ask this, would this be possible if I were to leave the container format as mp4? I'm not locked into the m3u8 format or HLS as long as I can accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @RPK Sure, but player support for mov_text is not universal. `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i eng.vtt -i spa.vtt -map 0 -map 1 -map 2 -c copy -c:s mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:1 language=spa -movflags +faststart output.mp4`

Comment: These video files are for mobile consumption on both iOS and Android, so I'll have to do some digging to test whether or not those platforms support mov_text. I'm marking this answer as correct. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @RPK mov_text is MPEG-4 Timed Text (MP4TT), or MPEG-4 Streaming text format. See ISO/IEC 14496-17. Sometimes called *3gpp timed text* (technically incorrect for MP4).